# Pytorch Android Expected Tuple but got String ()

Tags: android, pytorch

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.facebook.jni.CppException: isTuple()
INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h":1396, please report a bug to PyTorch. Expected Tuple but got String ()
Exception raised from toTuple at ../aten/src/ATen/core/ivalue_inl.h:1396 (most recent call first):
(no backtrace available)
```

upadate on

```
implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android_lite:1.12.1
implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchvision_lite:1.10.0'
```

in my build.gradle file. it worked for me.

Comment: seems to be related to [this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/issues/267)